# If a confidence interval and test error are both expressions of a margin of error, why do we need both?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, error

Let's say:

1. We have a population consisting of $N$ units, of which we take a sample of $n$ observations. For simplicity, this will be a bivariate dataset $(X, Y)$, whose true population is best modelled by a simple linear regression.
2. Of these $n$ observations, we randomly remove 20% so as to be used as a Test Set later.
3. With the remaining 80% observations, we try fitting various regression models. We use a cross-validation approach, such as k-Fold CV, to obtain Validation Set errors (estimates for the test error). Assume the loss function is the squared error.
4. We find that the Validation Set error is lowest for the simple linear regression, and therefore take this model forward.
5. We use bootstrapping to generate confidence and prediction intervals around this linear regression line. Example image below.

[image: Example linear regression with confidence and prediction intervals]

6. We fit the linear regression model on the 80% observations, and finally evaluate it's performance on the test set, yielding a Test Set error.

**My questions is this:**

*What is the difference between what the confidence/prediction interval is telling us, and the validation and/or test set error? Am I not correct in saying that these are both expressions of a margin of error, and therefore I'm finding it difficult to understand why we do both? I hope this makes sense.*

Thank you